# how to calculate percentage of nulls for each column for a table in athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

We have a huge table with 80+ columns in athena.

As part of data validation, we are trying to check what percentage of data is null
Is there a generic query to check the same.

I tried similar query like this below :

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(c1) as CountColumn, 
  (CAST (COUNT(c1) as bigint/COUNT(*))*100 as PercentageOfNonNullValues
FROM t1;
```

But is there any simple way instead of writing for each column ( and we have 80+ columns )

Comment: If you have so many columns then your table design is probably wrong. Can you change it?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any simple way instead of writing for each column ( and we have 80+ columns )

You can leverage `information_schema` and the [`format()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) function to *generate* your query, but you need to write application logic for that, you cannot do this all within single Presto query.